# $l^p$ is super subset of $ l^q$ if and only if?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$$
l^p \subseteq l^q.
$$

if and only if ?

$l^p$ is a subset of $l^q$ when is it possible ? !

Comment: $l^p$ is a subspace of $l^q$ iff $p<=q$.

Comment: @Emin can you give a proof for this please ?!

Comment: see example 2 in http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/ottobre/fa/sol.pdf

Comment: p.s. I forgot to mention that it needs to be p,q>1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$ then we have $l^p \subsetneq l^q$.

**Proof:**

For the inclusion $l^p \subset l^q$:

The case $q= \infty$ is clear.

Now let $q< \infty$ and let $x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in l^p$. We want to show that 
$$||x||_{l^q} \leq ||x||_{l^p}.$$

Note that this inequality is independent under multiplying $x$ with a scalar $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence we can assume without loss of generality that $||x||_{l^p}=1$.
From this it follows that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $|x_n| \leq 1$. Hence also $|x_n|^q \leq |x_n|^p$. With this the inequality and therefore also the inclusion immediately follow.

For the strict inequality $l^p \neq l^q$ consider the element $x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  with $x_n=n^{-1/p}$ which lies in $l^q$ but not in $l^p$.

This concludes the proof of the statement at the beginning.

Remark: Clearly we also have $l^p \subset l^q$ if $1 \leq p = q \leq \infty$.